# IE Conditional Statement for ALL IE Not Working

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

The conditional statement for all versions of IE is not working properly. The styles to be applied to IE only are not taking effect in any version of IE. I have checked the mapping to ie.css and it is correct yet no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <!--[if IE]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css">
        <![endif]-->
        </head>
```

Comment: What versions of IE are you testing?  The newer ones don't support conditional comments

Comment: IE10 and IE11 don't support conditional comments. However, later IE versions are also also pretty good at being standards-compliant, so you really shouldn't need an IE-specific stylesheet in most cases, especially as you're using the HTML5 doctype. (having said that, you should check your document mode to make sure you aren't in compatibility mode, and also use the W3C validator to check your HTML is valid, as either of these could throw things out)

Comment: I am looking to target IE 9 down to IE7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of IE 10, conditional comments are no longer supported.

From Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX

> Important  As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no
>   longer supported by standards mode. Use feature detection to provide
>   effective fallback strategies for website features that aren't
>   supported by the browser. For more info about standards mode, see
>   Defining Document Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I found this CSS trick that seems to work on all versions of IE. Thank you everyone. :)

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
 .selector { property:value; }
 }
```